# добавить символ в конец строки

Tags: python

Всем привет! делаю скрипт по изменению строк, замена последнего символа строки получилась (спасибо здешним спецам по Python), а вот с добавлением нового символа проблема. Почему то ничего не добавляет на else (нужно к строке, которая попадает на else добавить символ). Плюс чувствую копчиком что обилие строк с elif можно заменить одной строкой:

```
#скрипт заменяет цифру на следующую в конце, если в конце буква- добавляет цифру 1
inp = open (inp.txt', 'r')
out = open ('out.txt', 'w')
#тут читаю файл построчно
for line in inp:
    # Удаляем символы переноса строки с конца
    line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
    # Записываем всю строку, кроме последнего символа
    out.write(line[:-1])
    # Проверяем последний символ
    if line[-1] == '1':
        out.write('2')
    elif line[-1] == '2':
        out.write('3')
    elif line[-1] == '3':
        out.write('4')
    elif line[-1] == '4':
        out.write('5')
    elif line[-1] == '5':
        out.write('6')
    elif line[-1] == '6':
        out.write('7')
    elif line[-1] == '7':
        out.write('8')
    elif line[-1] == '8':
        out.write('9')
    elif line[-1] == '9':
        out.write('0')                          
    else:
        line.join('1')
    # Добавляем перенос строки
    out.write('\n')
inp.close()    
out.close()
print ('Работа завершена. Изменено '+ str(sum(1 for line in open('out.txt', 'r'))) + str(' строк'))
```

Comment: line.join('1') вы забыли out.write

Comment: да точно, out.write помог добавить символ, но незадача в том, что на else я хочу не удалять конец строки (как это делается тут # Записываем всю строку, кроме последнего символа
    out.write(line[:-1])), а к существующей строке, которая попадает под условие else добавить цифру 1 (увеличить длину строки на 1 символ)

Comment: Попробуйте: out.write(line+'1')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверку на цифру можно сделать без try-except, а функцией `isdigit()` как в соседнем ответе. Суть в том, что незачем держать массив или делать большое ветвление, если значения у нас связаны. Т.е. записываем цифру больше на единицу. А если было 9, записываем последнюю цифру числа 10.

```
with open('inp.txt') as inp, open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
    # Счётчик строк
    count = 0
    #тут читаю файл построчно
    for line in inp:
        # Удаляем символы переноса строки с конца
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        # Записываем всю строку, кроме последнего символа
        out.write(line[:-1])
         # Проверяем последний символ
    try:
        number = int(line[-1])
    except ValueError:
        number = 0
    # Добавляем число, увеличенное на 1
    # Берём последний символ на случай, если получилось 10
    # Добавляем перенос строки
    out.write(str(number + 1)[-1] + '\n')
    count += 1
print('Работа завершена. Изменено', count, 'строк')
```

Comment: try/except лучше поближе к `int()` (чтобы случайных срабатываний из-за других вызовов исключить: `try: number = int(line[-1]) except ValueError: number = 0 $ print(number+1, file=out)`

Comment: @jfs, ок, вынес int() из try-except. print() не стал писать, чтобы везде одинаково было. Всё равно там строка нужна, чтобы от 10 взять последний символ. Ну или % 10 надо было делать.

Comment: Отступ неправильный

Comment: Работает код, хотя как пишет Лутц, для Python очевидный путь- правильный, а очевидный путь мне кажется elif)) Проблему с увеличением строки решил очень просто:  else:
        out.write(line[-1]+str('1'))

Comment: @dimahimma: `elif` вариант содержит чрезмерное повторения кода -- никаким образом это нельзя назвать идиоматическим кодом в Питоне (как try/except так и `dct.get(line[-1], '1')` являются лучшими альтернативами). А очевидность зависит от опыта: *"There is no intuitive interface, not even the nipple. It's all learned."*

Answer (score 1):

По поводу конструкции `if` можно сделать так:

```
dct = {
    '1':2,
    '2':3,
    '3':4,
    '4':5,
    '5':6,
    '6':7,
    '7':8,
    '8':9,
    '9':0
}

inp = open ('inp.txt', 'r')
out = open ('out.txt', 'w')
for line in inp:
    line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
    out.write(line[:-1])
    if line[-1].isdigit(): out.write(dct[line[-1]])
    out.write('\n')
inp.close()    
out.close()
```

Comment: лучше `dct.get(line[-1], '1')` и сохранить строки, а не цифры в словаре. `.isdigit()` в этом случае не нужен, который к тому же [может вернуть True даже для строк, на которых int не работает](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3033342/4279).